# Netgear GS324 port showing as connected when no cables connected

Tags: ethernet, switch

A GS324 port is lighting up with nothing connected to any Ethernet ports on it. Usually about 30 seconds after turning off and back on.

Home setup is as follows and has been working fine for nearly 2 years.
Have ISP router wired to patch panel and the patch panel port wired to my switch.
Have another router setup as an Access Point and this is wired back to patch panel and in turn to switch also.
I have a number of devices wried back to patch panel which are also wired to switch (TV, Alarm, Intercom, Etc..)

Everything stopped working yesterday and it looks like something odd is happening with the switch.
It is showing that there is a connection on port 12 (Orange light), even though I have nothing from my patch panel or directly wired to that switch port.
When I remove all cables from switch and power off/on the switch then port 12 lights up anyway also.

Also,Sometimes it takes a few minutes for port 12 to light up and devices on network will work until this point.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have another switch you could use temporarily to see if its a problem with the switch itself having issues?

Comment: Might be able to get a lend of one in work during the week.

Comment: The link lights lighting up even with nothing connected makes me think that theres something wrong with the switch. If its a managed switch working as a basic switch with no config, you could clear the running config and see if that helps at all. Either way, I would think that hooking up another switch might alleviate the problem.